# Gtk Notebook "change-current-page" doesn't work

Tags: ruby, gtk

i am using gtk notebook. I need to if user change current page, some
button should be active. But current-page-change doesn't work, so
nothing happens. I tried "switch-page" signal but it gives me previous
page number when i asked "notebook.page". But i need to if user change
current page, i should know which page is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `switch-page` signal sends the new page number as argument to the handler, so you can get it without asking the notebook.

The reason the notebook doesn't answer correctly is that when `switch-page` is handled, the switch did not yet complete. (This allows your handler to cancel the switch or switch to a different page.) To connect to the signal after the switch has been performed, call `connect_after`, in which case you'll get the new page number from the notebook.